# AR Configured AVD cannot run AR apps

Tags: android, arcore

According to the [Android Docs](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator) I should be able to run ARCore applications on the emulator. I've followed the instructions in the above link, but receive `This device does not support AR`.

```
Name: Pixel_2_API_28
CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
Path: /Users/ashley/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_28.avd
Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 28)
Skin: pixel_2
SD Card: 512 MB
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile: 
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: pixel_2
hw.lcd.width: 1080
hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
image.androidVersion.api: 28
tag.id: google_apis
hw.mainKeys: no
hw.camera.front: emulated
avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 2 API 28
hw.gpu.mode: auto
hw.ramSize: 1536
PlayStore.enabled: false
fastboot.forceColdBoot: no
hw.cpu.ncore: 4
hw.keyboard: yes
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
hw.dPad: no
hw.lcd.height: 1920
vm.heapSize: 256
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.gps: yes
hw.audioInput: yes
image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86/
showDeviceFrame: yes
hw.camera.back: virtualscene
AvdId: Pixel_2_API_28
hw.lcd.density: 420
hw.arc: false
hw.device.hash2: MD5:55acbc835978f326788ed66a5cd4c9a7
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no
fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes
hw.trackBall: no
hw.battery: yes
hw.sdCard: yes
tag.display: Google APIs
runtime.network.latency: none
disk.dataPartition.size: 800M
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

I'm developing on a 2018 13" MacBook Pro with Mojave as the OS. I don't know whether that has any bearing on the problem. How do I get ARCore to work in the virtual device?